# Send data to mysql database using AJAX post request

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I want to send user typed string via AJAX POST request and add to database:

```
Új gyártó: <input type="text" id="new_mfg" size="20">
<button id="add_mfg">Hozzáadás</button>
<script>
    $("#add_mfg").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var new_mfg = $('#new_mfg').val();
        //$(this).text(new_mfg);                    
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST","/phps/add_mfg.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send('$new_mfg');
    });
</script>
```

Here is the add_mfg.php script:

```
require_once('login.php');

$new_mfg = $_POST['new_mfg'];
$new_mfg = stripslashes($new_mfg);

$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if(!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MYSQL:" . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
    or die("Unable to select database:" . mysql_error());
$query = "INSERT INTO mfg(ID, mfg_name) VALUES(NULL, '$new_mfg')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($db_server);
```

The code doesn't work and I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: why don´t you use JQuery ajax method? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Is the request sending to add_mfg.php.Do you have any error in the console?

Comment: As a matter of fact, you cannot send data to mysql databse using AJAX post request. You can send it to PHP script only

Comment: Nope, I dont have any error log. I'll try to change to jquery ajax method, but does it matter for this case?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your click event handler into `$(document).ready(function(){  });`

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#add_mfg").click(function(e){

});
});
```

Comment: or the shortcut $(function(){});

Comment: @user874774 Yes...But i think OP is newbie so its easier for him to google it.

Comment: even you need to replace `new XMLHttpRequest();` request with `$.ajax({});`

Comment: I think there is no problem with the jquery event. My first tough was the same, but I tried to print out the readed new_mfg variable:

Answer (score 0):

Use this short version:

```
$(function() {
  $("#add_mfg").click(function(e){
      // ...
  });
});
```